# Objective-C exceptions and Flex mobile ANE

Tags: ios, xcode, apache-flex

I am working on this ANE where I am having this issue whereby the @catch clause of the Objective-C code is not executed. The application just crash whenever an exception is thrown. Seems like exceptions in native code are not supported. I have also tried the to add the -fobjc-exceptions flag as an option to my ios-platformoptions.xml file but this resulted in an "ld: unknown option" error.

Could anybody confirm and/or perhaps post some Adobe documentation weather exceptions in native code are supported or not, or am I doing something wrong? How can I enforce and enable exceptions?

Comment: And thus - one of the 9,000 problems with using ANE's.